# C# WinForms DevExpress и EntityFramework добавление и сохранение в базу данных

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, entity-framework, devexpress

Не совсем понимаю почему происходит так. Когда добавляю новую запись по шаблону и сохраняю новые значения все нормально. Добавляется в базу и обновляется grid. А когда пытаюсь обновить значения имеющейся строки в базе обновления проходят, но в grid старые значения. Я неправильно работаю с контекстом? Привожу код.

Есть форма1

```
    public partial class IncidentJournal : Form
    {
        VGSOContext db;
        public IncidentJournal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            db = new VGSOContext();
            db.IncidentJournal.Load();
            db.CorrectiveAction.Load();
            dateEdit1.EditValue = DateTime.Now;
        }
   private void LoadMainGrid(int y, int m)
        {
                gridMainGrid.DataSource = db.IncidentJournal.Where(p => p.IncidentDatetime.Year == y && p.IncidentDatetime.Month == m).ToList();
        }
   private void IncidentJournal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int y = dateEdit1.DateTime.Year;
            int m = dateEdit1.DateTime.Month;
            LoadMainGrid(y, m);
        }
private object ShowSomething(object r)
        {
            EditIncidentJournal f2 = new EditIncidentJournal(r);
            f2.ShowDialog();
            return f2.SomeData;
        }
private void SBAddIncJournal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(gridViewMain.GetRowCellValue(gridViewMain.FocusedRowHandle, "Id").ToString());
            using (var t = new VGSOContext())
            {
                var i = t.IncidentJournal.Where(x => x.Id == id).Single();
                object j = ShowSomething(i);
                i = (VGSO.Models.IncidentJournal)j;
                t.IncidentJournal.Add(i);
                t.SaveChanges();
            }
            LoadMainGrid(dateEdit1.DateTime.Year, dateEdit1.DateTime.Month);
}

private void SBEditIncJournal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(gridViewMain.GetRowCellValue(gridViewMain.FocusedRowHandle, "Id").ToString());
            var i2 = db.IncidentJournal.Where(x => x.Id == id).Single();
            using (var c = new VGSOContext())
            {
                var i = c.IncidentJournal.Where(x => x.Id == id).Single();
                object j = ShowSomething(i);
                i = (VGSO.Models.IncidentJournal)j;
                c.IncidentJournal.Attach(i);
                c.Entry(i).State = EntityState.Modified;
                c.SaveChanges();
                i2 = i;
            }
            LoadMainGrid(dateEdit1.DateTime.Year, dateEdit1.DateTime.Month);
}
```

Вторая форма

```
public partial class EditIncidentJournal : Form
    {
        VGSOContext db = new VGSOContext();

        public object SomeData { get; private set; }

        public EditIncidentJournal(object somedata)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SomeData = somedata ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(somedata));
            db.rCehs.Load();
            db.rObjects.Load();
            comboCehs.DataSource = db.rCehs.ToList();
            comboObjects.DataSource = db.rObjects.ToList();
        }

        private void EditIncidentJournal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VGSOContext c = new VGSOContext();
            if (SomeData is Models.IncidentJournal)
            {
                var ss = (Models.IncidentJournal)SomeData;
                comboCehs.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", ss, "CehId", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
                comboObjects.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", ss, "ObjectId", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
                MEIncidentType.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ss, "IncidentType", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
                DEIncidentTime.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Datetime", ss, "IncidentDatetime", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
                MEReason.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ss, "Reason", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
                MEIntelligence.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ss, "Intelligence", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
                MEDuration.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ss, "Duration", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
                MEAmountDamage.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ss, "AmountDamage", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
                MEResponsiblePersons.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ss, "ResponsiblePersons", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
            }
        }

        private void SBSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void SBCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Прошу помочь в понимании. Спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте закомментировать `db.IncidentJournal.Load();`

Answer (score 1):

Выполнив `db.IncidentJournal.Load();` вы создаёте кэш всей(!) таблицы в памяти приложения. Далее каждый раз вызывая ваш метод `LoadMainGrid()` вы делаете выборку именно из кэша. Помимо наблюдаемого вами неприятного поведения, вызов `Load()` для всей таблицы также будет создавать проблемы с производительностью по мере роста количества записей. Мое мнение, что в вашем случае нужно просто убрать вызов этого метода из кода и всё.